# Blender 2.9: Problem With : Flip Normal Faces

Tags: mesh, normals

When I Export (.fxb) file to (unity 5) i find out faces was flipped,

[image]
when i go back to blender to fix it , i found out when i do (Alt+N) for flipping normals its just flip one face side  and the other face side is not visible

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z93OB.png)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable `backface-culling` in **Blender** and **Unity**.

## Blender

[image]

## Unity

I have not used Unity in a long time; but I think you need to toggle the option `cull-off` found in the `SunShader` section I believe?

Comment: I am so sorry for not responding early, I have a hard couple of days of work.
Ok Mester I will do a little google searching about the (SunShader), I'm really thankful for the unity community, guys your so helpful and nice persons I really appreciate for lighting my mind

Comment: No problem, glad to help! If my post does indeed turn-out to be the question's answer, please consider marking it as the thread solution if you deem it appropriate.